# How can I find this regular expression for replace_all?

Tags: java, regex

I have tried a lot but coul'nd find a way to combine these two regular expressions in replace_all.

```
"test String".replaceAll("(?i)[^a-zßäöü]", " ").replaceAll(" +", " "));
```

The first regex deletes every symbol, that is not part of the german and the second regex deletes every space combination 2 or more.
(How can i say, that it should be 2 or more space? Because + means at least 1, right?)

Thanks :)

Comment: You can express "find 2 or more spaces with " {2,}". But what do you mean with "combine these two regular expressions in replace_all"?

Comment: How can i make 1 regular expression from these 2 expressions ?

Comment: How would this 2 groups look like in my case ?

Comment: Why can't you simply use `replaceAll("(?i)[^a-zßäöü ]+", " ")`?

Comment: What does the + mean, at the end of the regular expression ?

Comment: @Human What do you mean by "What does the + mean"? You used it in your code earlier in your second replacing method `replaceAll(" +", " ")`. Its meaning didn't change, it still is quantifier representing *one or more occurrences*.

Comment: The regular expression dont work. Because i remove symbols with space and want to remove the spaces. In this case i cant combine these expressions easily

Comment: Try with `replaceAll("(?i)[^a-zßäöü]+", " ")` (without that space at the end of `[^..]`). If it doesn't work as intended post example of input text and expected output.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases combining your replaces is not that easy since first replace may produce some result which should be included in second replace.

In your case

1. you are simply replacing non `a-zßäöü` with space,
2. and later replacing two or more spaces with one.

In other words if you have data like `"ab.,!@#cd    ef` it will be transformed at first into `ab     cd    ef` and later into `ab cd ef`.

In other words you are replacing set of one or more characters which are not the ones you are accepting with one space. So you probably should be fine with simple

```
replaceAll("(?i)[^a-zßäöü]+", " ") // space is also included in [^a-zßäöü] 
                                   // but that should be fine since replacing 
                                   // space with space shouldn't break anything
                                   // (especially if it worked in your original solution)
```

Comment: Am I missing something or have you left out a space from the character class?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes. Since space is also represented by `[^a-zßäöü]` and OP doesn't want to have more than two continues spaces I thought it would be nice to also replace them along with rest of unwanted characters. For instance in case of `a! .-b` will become `a b`. If I use regex like `[^a-zßäöü ]` then original spaces wouldn't be handled so I would need to handle them in another replace (and that is what OP is trying to avoid).